# What ffmpeg command line will list the key frames?

Tags: ffmpeg

What ffmpeg command line will list the index numbers of the key frames in an existing .MP4 to stdout?

I've tried the only applicable answer at https://superuser.com/questions/885452/extracting-the-index-of-key-frames-from-a-video-using-ffmpeg to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -v trace 2>&1 | grep -B 1 "distance 1, keyframe 0" | grep "distance 0, keyframe 1"
```

This will emit lines of the form,

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000000000405740] AVIndex stream 0, sample 3961, offset 2e0d298, dts 2028032, size 37168, distance 0, keyframe 1
```

where the number after sample is the frame count, zero-indexed.

I have two greps since typically all audio samples are tagged as keyframes, so the first grep searches for the frame *after* a keyframe and the 2nd grep only emits the line earlier to the matched frame, which is the KF. If you know the stream index for the video, you could fashion a regex and use a single grep.

Comment: Thanks but that fails here with ' Invalid loglevel "trace" '.

Comment: Your ffmpeg build is likely too old.

Comment: Thanks. Switching to the latest cured that. But failed on (MKS) grep -B unknown option.. Do you have a solution that works with latest ffmpeg on OOTB Windows? Else how can I capture that ffmpeg listing to a file? The usual redirects aren't working for me. Thanks.

Comment: Add -report to the command; it will generate a log file in working directory.

Comment: Thanks. I find I must have messed up the redirects, since now I find 2> works. Sad to see ffmpeg is abusing stderr here.

Comment: I have a feeling your grep pair will fail if two video keyframes are on successive frames.

Comment: How is ffmpeg abusing stderr? It can stream data on stdout, so all messages only go out on stderr.

Comment: *your grep pair will fail if two video keyframes are on successive frames* --> correct, but that would be due to very weird content or badly configured encoder. Usually when an encoder finds it inefficient to code a frame as inter-predicted and the prior KF is very close, the usual strategy is to code it as non-KF I-frame.

Comment: Actually since weird content or bad encoding is exactly the kind of thing we'd expect to use this data to debug, I'd say no this fail is due to the the grep, not the data. Thanks anyway for the suggestion.

Comment: "How is ffmpeg abusing stderr" Since my raising of that subject was immediately followed by me receiving a conversation warning, we'd better keep that subject out of this question.

Comment: I'll go with >>> ffmpeg -i output.mp4 -v trace 2>&1 | grep "distance 0, keyframe 1" <<< (GOK why this comment input bars formatting) with a note that this will include audio too (at least until ffmpeg stops misrepping audio samples as key frames). Thanks.